# Accessing a constant in module configuration with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

This page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers has a table at the bottom which states that both constants and providers are available in config phase.

When I try to use some constant in my config I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The constant is set up as follows:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('services.config', [])
  .constant('configuration', {
    key: 'value';
  });
```

then the configuration is:

```
   angular
      .module('testApp', ['services.config', 'ngRoute'])
      .config(function ($routeProvider, configuration) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });


        // do something with configuration.key - causes error


      });
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.constant('configuration', {
    key: 'value'
  });

app.config(function (configuration) {    
    console.log(configuration.key); //value           
      });

app.constant('configuration', {
    key: 'value'
  });
```

here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopinathshiva/0701k7ke/8/

Comment: I have tried renaming the first module as per your suggestion to testApp. I then remove the dependency on the `'services.config'` module in my  module definition but I get the same problem.  Could it be an issue that this code is in two separate files? The <script> import for the service.config module is imported into my index.html before the code in the second file that configures the testApp module.

Comment: if the code is written in 2 seperate js files, then import config file first before importing any files